# Spring framework Access Session Variables in helper classes

Tags: java, spring, session

Following is my code structure

```
Filter A{


   Helper B()                    // Call to Helper B
   int a= HelperA.function();   
}
```

Like these There are multiple helper classes and multiple function calls being made

```
Helper B{

   // Set the attributes in here Value in here 
}



HelperA{

 function(){

   // Using the Session values 
 }
}
```

I am not able to relate how to use the sessionattribute notation in this case

Is there a property in Spring framework that will set the session value and can be accessed from any part of the  Spring application
There are too many function calls and it will be lot of tedious task to change the signature of all the methods

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use spring bean in this scenario, create bean keep it in http session scope. 
for this you can find configuration [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other). and then use the same bean in controllers. not sure weather it can be used in conjunction with sessionattribute annotation.